# cumsum() on multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a multi-index dataframe that shows the sum of transactions on a monthly frequency.

I am trying to get a cumsum() on yearly basis that respects my 'mapid' and 'service' multi-index. However I don't know how to derive that data

```
combined_df = combined_df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'provider', 'mapid', 'service']).sum()


                                                 cost
datetime   provider mapid   service                  
2017-08-31 Amazon   10147.0 Monitor              0.41
                            Storage             90.51
                            Virtual Machine  11646.32
2017-09-30 Amazon   10147.0 Monitor              0.89
                            Storage            226.06
                            Virtual Machine  32624.91
2017-10-31 Amazon   10147.0 Monitor              0.17
                            Storage            261.72
                            Virtual Machine  36934.93
2017-11-30 Amazon   10147.0 Monitor              0.35
                            Storage            269.06
                            Virtual Machine  30790.70
```

I would like to derive the follow results

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Group on the last level of your `MultiIndex` and call `DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`:

```
combined_df['cumsum'] = combined_df.groupby(level=-1)['cost'].cumsum()
```

Comment: That was it! Are you able to explain how it still respects my first three indexes

Comment: @Karun You'll have to thank the pandas devs for that. If you're grouping on a certain level of a MultiIndex, the other levels are left untouched.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more general way (which does not assume you are grouping by the last level of your index):

```
combined_df['cumsum'] = combined_df.groupby(['datetime', 'provider', 'mapid'])['cost'].cumsum()
```

i.e. you leave out in the groupby statement the column you want to cumsum on.