# Pandas Cumulative sum over 1 indice but not the other 3

Tags: pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I have a dataframe with 4 variables DIVISION, QTR, MODEL_SCORE, MONTH with the sum of variable X aggregated by those 4.

I would like to effective partition the data by DIVISION,QTR, and MODEL SCORE and keep a running total order the MONTH FIELD order smallest to largest. The idea being it would reset if it got to a new permutation of the other 3 columns

```
df = df.groupby(['DIVISION','MODEL','QTR','MONTHS'])['X'].sum()
```

I'm trying

```
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(level=3)['X'].cumsum()
```

having tried all numbers I can think in the level argument. It seems be able to work any way other than what I want.

EDIT: I know the below isn't formatted ideally, but basically as long as the only variable changing was MONTH the cumulative sum would continue but any other variable would cause it to reset.

```
DIVSION QTR  MODEL  MONTHS  X  CUMSUM
      A   1    1       1 10      10
      A   1    1       2 20      30
      A   1    2       1  5       5
```

Comment: It's best if you can provide a small sample data and expected output from there.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying to figure out formatting

Comment: Copy/Paste the output of `print(df.head().to_string())`, it should be sufficient.

Comment: `.sum(['X'])` does not do what you think it does. In [groupby sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) your code is equivalent to `df = df.groupby(['DIVISION','MODEL','QTR','MONTHS']).sum(numeric_only=['X'])` and `['X']` being a non-empty list is truthy.

Comment: @HenryEcker I'm not sure I understand sorry to be clear the sum in the first line of code is just to set up the dataframe of a much bigger sample to cumulative sum over.

Comment: I edited your dataframe. Please check if I don't make mistake.

Comment: Your code `df.groupby(['DIVISION','MODEL','QTR','MONTHS']).sum(['X'])` is equivalent to `df.groupby(['DIVISION','MODEL','QTR','MONTHS']).sum(numeric_only=True)` I was stating that I do not think that is what you meant by passing `['X']` as an argument to `groupby sum`

Comment: @HenryEcker I think I know what you mean now I have edited as such.

Comment: @Corralien your edit looks what I want. Basically in my data, it doesn't reset the cumulative sum correctly regardless of what I do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400485/cumsum-on-multi-index-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Where is the `MODEL` column?

Comment: I believe it's updated correctly now, Sorry I have to change my data names from the actual source. Part of the confusion for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for all the trouble I believe the answer was way simpler than I was making it to be.

After

```
df = df.groupby(['DIVISION','MODEL','QTR','MONTHS'])['X'].sum()
```

I was supposed to reset the index I did not want a multi-index and this appears to have worked.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(['DIVISION','MODEL','QTR'])['X'].cumsum()
```

Comment: `df = df.groupby(['DIVISION','MODEL','QTR','MONTHS'], as_index=False)['X'].sum()` should also work if you want to avoid the MultiIndex without needing to `reset_index` later.